# Calculate if a bullet hits the balloon

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have this problem I can't figure out and need help.
The problem is about calculating how many balloons are hit by a pellet gun. Balloons positions are described by 3D coordinates *(X,Y,Z)* and radius R. The gunshot is defined by 3D location of the end of the barrel "p" *(Px,Py,Pz)* and vector "v" *(Vx, Vy, Vz)* describing the direction barrel is pointing to.

I've tried to implement the solution suggested here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939423/calculate-if-vector-intersects-sphere

```
// C = center of sphere
// r = radius of sphere
// P = point on line
// U = unit vector in direction of line

Q = P - C;
a = U*U;      // should be = 1
b = 2*U*Q
c = Q*Q - r*r;
d = b*b - 4*a*c;  // discriminant of quadratic

if d <  0 then solutions are complex, so no intersections
if d >= 0 then solutions are real, so there are intersections
```

But the problem with this is that I get intersection with balloons that are positioned behind the gun. How can I modify this algorithm in order to produce the correct result? Or is my approach maybe wrong?

Comment: How are you representing points and vectors?

Comment: I suggest you ask your question on  Mathematics Stack Exchange since it's mostly a math question.

Comment: In addition, you can verify that the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) between `v` and `balloon - p` is greater than zero, which means their angle is < 90 deg.

Comment: A point is represented with real number values x,y,z. A vector is also represented with real number values x,y,z. All shot coordinates are in [-10,10] range.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually solve the quadratic equation defined by your variables a, b and c.
Often, there are math libraries to do this, something like:

`(t1,t2) = QuadraticSolve(a, b, c);`

You can also do it manually for each parameter:

```
t1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
t2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
```

If t1 or t2 is positive then that intersection is in front of your gun.